# In Matlab, is it possible to concatenate matrices with brace indexing?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to concatenate a matrix of the form `A  = [A ; a]` but where I have a loop. So in fact, something along the lines of

```
for j=1:H
for k=1:N
      
     Z{j} = zeros(T-j,N);
     Z{j}(:,k) = ones(T-j,1);
     
     A{j}=[];
     A{j}=[A{j}; Z{j}];
end
end
```

The issue I am having is that whilst I do  get `A{j}` for `1` to `H`, the inside elements are not working for some reason. Basically `A{j}=[A{j}; Z{j}];` does not seem to work for some reason. Is it because it is brace indexed?

Answer (score 3):

I realised that I had to move `A{j}=[];` out of the `k` loop, so this works perfectly as I wanted:

```
for j=1:H

A{j}=[];

for k=1:N
      
     Z{j} = zeros(T-j,N);
     Z{j}(:,k) = ones(T-j,1);
     
     A{j}=[A{j}; Z{j}];
end
end
```